# How to calculate 20% change within one hour in Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

I have to compare two values changing in both directions (rising and falling) within an hour (items amount, for example). What formula may I use to calculate if the amount drops or rises on more than 20%? Does Zabbix calculated value support if conditions to support positive and negative change or it's possible to bypass it?

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
{api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers.count(0)}/{api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers.count(,,,1h)}*100 > 20
```

but what if mysql.get_active_offers.count(0) more than mysql.get_active_offers.count(,,,1h) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a "Simple Change" preprocessor because:

> If the current value is smaller than the previous value, Zabbix
>   discards that difference (stores nothing) and waits for another value.

If you set the item with a 1h check interval (or with scheduled intervals at a specific minute of every hour), you can do the trick with the `last()` [function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions).

Let's say that at 12:00 your item equals 25 and at 13:00 it equals 38:

- At 13:00 invoking `last()` without parameters will return 38
- At 13:00 invoking `last(#2)` will return 25

You can calculate the hourly readings delta % with:

```
100 * ({api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers.last()} - {api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers.last(#2)}) / {api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers.last(#2)}
```

This syntax should work either in a trigger or in a calculated item, choose the one that suits you better: I suggest a calculated item.

Of course, your trigger will have a double condition: you need to match `"> 20" OR "< -20"`

If you don't want to change the item's check interval you can use the `avg()` function, see the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions).

Comment: In other words, the correct expression will look like this, right? 

(100 * ({api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers_per_hour.last()} - {api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers_per_hour.last(#2)}) / {api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers_per_hour.last(#2)} > 20) or (100 * ({api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers_per_hour.last()} - {api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers_per_hour.last(#2)}) / {api20prod:mysql.get_active_offers_per_hour.last(#2)} < -20)

Comment: Yes, that should do it!

Comment: The only question - why we divide on #2?

Comment: To get the % increase you have first to calculate the delta between values (`last()-last(#2)`), then solve the proportion `last(#2)/100 = delta/x`. The value of `last(#2)` is your 100%, x is the % increase/decrease, depending on the sign.  Here's a simple explanation: https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/percent-change.html